# JavaScript's localStorage doesn't keep value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have:

```
var setFileName = function(argFileName)
{
    localStorage.fileName = argFileName;
    fileNameElem.value = localStorage.fileName;
};

var getFileName = function()
{
    return localStorage.fileName ? localStorage.fileName : getDefaultFileName();
};
```

`setFileName()` works because `fileNameElem` contains `argFileName`. But whenever I call `getFileName()` it always returns `getDefaultFileName()`

Why is that?

Comment: please check this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I can't see the immediate problem, but FWIW your ternary operator can be replaced with `return localStorage.fileName || getDefaultFileName()`

Comment: @Alnitak. Ok i change it

Comment: Your code works for me.  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using this syntax

To store use

```
localStorage.setItem('fileName', value);
```

to get from the local storage

```
localStorage.getItem('filename');
```

Edited with a jsfiddle just in case you want to take a look.

https://jsfiddle.net/fo38uo9t/1/

Comment: Per the [W3C specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface)  it is _completely legal_ to use property accessors to read and write from `localStorage`.   The only exception is when wanting to store a property that happens to share a name with a real property (or one inherited via the prototype chain of the `localStorage` object)

Comment: @Alnitak well I changed it to "you should be using".  For some reason I just thought that syntax was not valid. Anyway it seems safer to use set & get, right?

Comment: Safer, perhaps, but almost certainly not the reason for the OP's problem.

Comment: I'm watching in Chrome the contents of `localStorage`. First it shows the assigned value but then quickly changes to `getDefaultFileName()`

Comment: @mirsadhalilovic which implies that you have some other code overwriting it, and that this answer did not actually solve your problem